# datetime daily comparison, fill month with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One contains information on an entry date and the other has returns from a company. I want to fill all dates in the return dataframe BEFORE the entry days with NaN. I achieved this by using the following code:

```
a.head(4)
        date   RET         Company
0 2015-04-16   1.764052    A
1 2015-04-17   0.400157    A
2 2015-04-18   0.978738    A
3 2015-04-19   2.240893    A


b.head(4)
        Entry  Company   
0 2015-04-17   A   
1 2017-04-03   B   
2 2018-04-04   C
3 2011-03-01   D

a['RET'][a['date'] < b["Entry"].iloc[0])] = np.NaN
```

But now I would like to fill that whole month with NaN instead of only the days before the date. This means if dataframe b has for example an entry date 2015-04-17, then all returns from dataframe a in 2015-04 need to be filled with NaN. I tried something like:

```
a['RET'][a['date'].strftime("%Y%m") < b["Entry"].iloc[i].strftime("%Y%m"))] = np.NaN
```

But it didn't work. Any recommendations how this can be done? thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think you can equal it with a np.NaN value. Doesn't it have to be an array?
did you try with [np.NaN] ?

Comment: Equaling with np.NaN worked in the first line of code. [np.NaN]  does unfortunately not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve with one merge and a double check

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'RET':[123,134,321,789,761,812],
                  'DATE':['2015-03-22','2015-04-15','2015-04-16','2015-04-17',
                          '2017-03-25','2017-04-02'],
                  'COMPANY':['A','A','A','A','B','B']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'ENTRY':['2015-04-17','2017-04-03'],
                  'COMPANY':['A','B']})

a['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(a['DATE'])
b['ENTRY'] = pd.to_datetime(b['ENTRY'])
b['ENTRY_month'] = b['ENTRY'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-01')).astype(np.datetime64)

ab = a.merge(b, on='COMPANY')
a.loc[(ab.ENTRY_month < ab.DATE)&(ab.ENTRY > ab.DATE), 'RET'] = np.nan
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if there are problems